# how to make modal to center in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

How I make my box to center like justify content center but with position absolute ?
top: '50%' is too close to the bottom its not centered.

Modal.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Pressable, StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector, GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, { runOnJS, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

interface IModalCenter {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onPress: () => void;
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
}

const ModalCenter = ({ children, onPress, style }: IModalCenter) => {
  const x = useSharedValue(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    x.value = 1;
  }, []);

  const aView = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const scale = withSpring(x.value);
    return {
      transform: [{ scale }]
    }
  });
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={s.container}>

      <Animated.View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',}} />

      <Animated.View style={[style, aView]}>
        { children }
      </Animated.View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  )
};

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 600,
    margin: 'auto'
  }
})

export default ModalCenter;
```

app.tsx

```
        <ModalCenter style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', position: 'absolute', margin: 'auto', alignSelf: 'center', height: 200, width: 300, borderRadius: 8, elevation: 4}} onPress={handleToggleModalMessage}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </ModalCenter>
```

[image]

how can i make it center ? ........................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'justify-content' property to the container:

```
 container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 600,
    margin: 'auto',
    justify-content: 'center' <---- add this
  }
```